# Devise and duo security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Has anyone one ever used Devise along with Duo security. It looks like I am going to have to override a lot of the devise session controller. Just curious if anyone else has gone down this path already and have some advice thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer or end up rolling your own? I am facing a similar path right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just overriding the devise session controller. Just the create action. So after a successful login it actually logs them back out and sends them to DUO login. If DUO login passes then it logs the user back in. Seems kinda convoluted, but it was really the only way I saw it working. Because if you don't log them back out before DUO they could just skip DUO through the URL.

Comment: Could you please tell what changes you made in create action ? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: there are a few different ways on github, this one uses the web-sdk https://github.com/billguy/devise_duo